# Is there a way to check if a ClickOnce application is running the latest version

Tags: clickonce

I understand that ClickOnce applications can update automatically.
However, the options offered by Microsoft are not what I am looking for.

If I check the version before the application starts, the startup is slower.

If I chek the version after the application starts, I don't know than a new version is available until the next startup.

I am looking for a boolean function to check if a new version is available. This would enable me to suggest to the user to restart the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

public bool IsUpdateAvailable()
{
    if (!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) return false;

    return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate();         
}
```

Of course, you might want to make this feature accessible via a button and wrap some UI around it, [like this](http://www.madprops.org/blog/Updating-ClickOnce-Application-Programatically/).