# How to deploy an auto-updating WCF windows service?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Windows service that is used locally only. I need to deploy it in multiple sites and I need the option to auto update it - when an update is released, the service has to be able to get the new version and update itself.
The service will be used in Windows 7, so the permission issue needs to be taken into account somehow.
I have no experience with services and their deployment, feel free to explain thoroughly.

**Edit**
I've been considering ClickOnce since another application I'm writing is deployed using it. The thing is, ClickOnce only checks for updates on startup and Windows services are supposed to be up and running.

1. Is it possible to use the ClickOnce detection in my other app and then update the service? (Permission-wise)
2. Can ClickOnce start and stop the service?
3. Can the update be silent?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take in account the expected availability of your service and the update policy for your application.

Besides that, you might want to take a look to:

[Is there a way to check if a ClickOnce application is running the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507209/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-clickonce-application-is-running-the-latest-version)

http://madprops.org/blog/Updating-ClickOnce-Application-Programatically/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the links, they might come on handy, but they're checking for available updates and I'd rather have it pushed somehow.